# How can I show a different button depending on item in array?

Tags: arrays, swift, button

In my app, users can hit a "next" button to increment to the next item in an array. That item then gets displayed in a label. As of now, I have over 80 items in the array. I'd like to show a different button depending on which array item is currently showing in the label. I'm still very new to coding, so I'm not really sure what to try first. I thought about adding a different button on my storyboard for each item and simply hiding it/unhiding it when its respective item is begin displayed, but I'm sure there is a better way than adding dozens of buttons. I'm guessing there will be use of if functions, which I understand how to use, but I guess I don't know how to make a button appear conditionally without first placing a button in the storyboard.

Comment: "guess I don't know how to make a button appear conditionally without first placing a button in the storyboard" Well, if you feel tied to the storyboard and you don't know how to make a button appear using code alone, that would be an excellent thing to learn first! Most professional apps are written with no storyboard at all; _all_ views are created completely in code. So that's an aspect of the art well worth mastering.

Comment: Another thing to realize is that an _existing_ button can be _modified_. So if "a difference button" means the same button except that it has a different title or other appearance feature, that's worth learning how to do too.